Can I use socket.io with typescript in AWS LAMBDA via AWS ALB?
I have one typescript repository which uses socketio and ioredis.
It listens to redis messages coming from one Laravel php application (ex: someone sent chat message via api call) and then dispatches those to the respective user socket.
"socket.io": "^4.7.5",
"ioredis": "^2.5.0",

I am thinking of deploying this service that now runs within one EC2 instance into AWS Lambda.
I can put a rule into the ALB that all GET /socket.io/* traffic gets redirected to my lambda.
I am using express.js in addition to socket.io
Thing is I am reading conflicting opinions online.
Some users say that it makes no sense to deploy into lambda as the connections are persistent and lambdas run for 15 minutes max, others say it is fine as not all chat users use it up to 15 minutes and lambdas can extend the time.
This is some sample code from my index.ts
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as http from 'http';
import * as https from 'https';

import express, { Application } from 'express';
import redis from 'ioredis/index';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken/index';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';

import BaseMultiuserChannel from './channels/BaseMultiuserChannel';
import NotificationChannel from './channels/NotificationChannel';
import config from './config';
import logger from './logger';
import { ChatMessageReceivedEvent, Message } from './types';
import { arrayContains } from './utilities';

const app: Application = express();
const io = new Server({
    allowEIO3: true,
});

const options = {
    jwtSecret: config.jwtSecret,
    authTimeout: 5000, // 5 seconds to send the authentication message
};

const httpServerPort = config.getenv('HTTP_PORT', 1605);
// @ts-ignore
const httpServer = http.Server(app);
io.attach(httpServer);
httpServer.listen(httpServerPort);
logger.info('http listening on port ' + httpServerPort + '...');

const httpsServerPort = config.getenv('HTTPS_PORT', -1);
if (httpsServerPort !== -1) {
    const ssl = {
        key: fs.readFileSync(config.getenv('SOCKETIO_SSL_KEY_FILE')),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(config.getenv('SOCKETIO_SSL_CERT_FILE')),
        ca: null,
    };

    // @ts-ignore
    const httpsServer = https.Server(ssl, app);
    io.attach(httpsServer);
    httpsServer.listen(httpsServerPort);
    logger.info('https listening on port ' + httpsServerPort + '...');
}

const notificationsChannels: Record<string, NotificationChannel> = {}; // A map of ad id to NotificationChannel object
const users: Record<
    string,
    {
        connections: Record<
            string,
            {
                joinedChannels: BaseMultiuserChannel[];
            }
        >;
    }
> = {};

const redisClient = redis.createClient(config.redis.port, config.redis.host);

// channels

const CHATS_CHANNEL = 'chat-room';

redisClient.subscribe(CHATS_CHANNEL);

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function
redisClient.psubscribe(NotificationChannel.channelPattern, function (err, count) {});

const onChatMessageV1 = function (channel: string, data: Message<ChatMessageReceivedEvent>) {
    const fromUserId = data.data.chatMessage.from || data.data.chatMessage.__from;
    delete data.data.chatMessage.__from;
    const receivingUsers = data.data.receivingUsers;

    logger.info('chat message from user id %s', fromUserId);

    for (const userId in users) {
        if (userId != fromUserId && arrayContains(receivingUsers, userId)) {
            logger.info('sending to user %s', userId);
            for (const socketId in users[userId].connections) {
                logger.info('sending to socket %s', io.sockets[socketId].id);

                io.sockets[socketId].emit<Omit<ChatMessageReceivedEvent, 'receivingUsers'>>(
                    `${channel}:${data.event}`,
                    {
                        chatId: data.data.chatId,
                        chatMessage: data.data.chatMessage,
                    },
                );
            }
        }
    }
};

const onMessage = function (channel: string, rawMsg: string) {
    const message = JSON.parse(rawMsg) as Message<unknown>;
    logger.info('New message on channel: %s, message: %s', channel, message.event);
    if (channel === CHATS_CHANNEL) {
        if (message.event === 'chat.messages.new.v1') {
            return onChatMessageV1(channel, message as unknown as Message<ChatMessageReceivedEvent>);
        } else {
            logger.error(`Unknown event of type ${message.event} in channel ${channel}`);
        }
    } else {
        logger.error(`Unknown channel ${channel}`);
    }
};

const onPmessage = function (pattern: string, channel: string, rawMsg: string) {
    const message = JSON.parse(rawMsg) as Message<unknown>;
    logger.info('New pmessage on channel %s, with pattern %s, event: ', channel, pattern, message.event);

    switch (pattern) {
        case NotificationChannel.channelPattern:
            if (!notificationsChannels[channel]) {
                notificationsChannels[channel] = new NotificationChannel(io, channel, logger);
            }
            return notificationsChannels[channel].handleMessage(message as Message<{ type: string }>);
    }
};

redisClient.on('pmessage', onPmessage);
redisClient.on('message', onMessage);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    logger.info('socket connected %s', socket.id);

    // temp delete socket from namespace connected map until authorized
    delete io.sockets[socket.id];

    const authTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        logger.warn(`Timeout auth passed, we are disconnecting socket ${socket.id}`);
        socket.disconnect(true);
    }, options.authTimeout || 5000);

    socket.on(
        'authenticate',
        function (
            data: {
                token: string;
                userId: string;
            },
            fn: (p: { success: boolean }) => void,
        ) {
            data.userId = data.userId.toString();
            logger.info('socket %s is trying to authenticate', socket.id);
            clearTimeout(authTimeout);
            jwt.verify(data.token, options.jwtSecret, function (err, decoded) {
                if (err || !decoded) {
                    logger.warn(`Cannot decode token ${data.token}`);
                    if (err) {
                        logger.warn(err);
                    }

                    return socket.disconnect(true);
                }
                if (decoded.sub != data.userId) {
                    logger.warn(`Provided userId ${data.userId} does not match token sub ${data.token}`);
                    return socket.disconnect(true);
                }

                // restore disabled connection
                io.sockets[socket.id] = socket;

                socket.data.decoded_token = decoded;
                socket.data.connectedAt = new Date();

                logger.info('User id %s with socket %s was authenticated', data.userId, socket.id);

                if (!users[data.userId]) {
                    users[data.userId] = {
                        connections: {},
                    };
                }

                users[data.userId].connections[socket.id] = { joinedChannels: [] };
                socket.data.user_id = data.userId;

                _logNrOfConnectedUsers();

                return fn({ success: true });
            });
        },
    );

    socket.on(
        'joinUserNotificationsChannel',
        function (data: { userId: string }, fn: (p: { success: boolean; channel?: string; error?: string }) => void) {
            data.userId = data.userId.toString();
            const result = NotificationChannel.formChannelName(data.userId);
            let channelName: string;

            if (result.success) {
                channelName = result.channelName!;
            } else {
                logger.warn('User %s failed to join notifications channel. Error: %s', data.userId, result.error);
                return fn({
                    success: false,
                    error: result.error,
                });
            }

            if (!notificationsChannels[channelName]) {
                notificationsChannels[channelName] = new NotificationChannel(io, channelName, logger);
            }

            users[data.userId].connections[socket.id].joinedChannels.push(notificationsChannels[channelName]);
            notificationsChannels[channelName].addUser(data.userId, socket.id);

            logger.debug('User %s joined notifications channel %s', data.userId, channelName);

            return fn({
                success: true,
                channel: channelName,
            });
        },
    );

    socket.on('disconnect', function (reason) {
        logger.info('Socket %s, user %s disconnected because of %s', socket.id, socket.data.user_id, reason);

        if (!socket.data.user_id || !users[socket.data.user_id]) {
            return;
        }

        const userId = socket.data.user_id!;
        const user = users[userId];

        for (const socketId in user.connections || []) {
            for (let i = 0; i < user.connections[socketId].joinedChannels.length; i++) {
                user.connections[socketId].joinedChannels[i].removeUserConnection(userId, socket.id);
            }
        }

        user.connections && user.connections[socket.id] && delete user.connections[socket.id];
        if (Object.keys(user.connections).length === 0) {
            delete users[userId];
        }

        _logNrOfConnectedUsers();
    });
});

function _logNrOfConnectedUsers(): void {
    const connectedUsers = Object.keys(users).length;
    logger.info('Number of connected users: %s', connectedUsers, {
        nrOfConnectedUsers: connectedUsers,
    });
}


I was thinking of using @vendia/serverless-express to create an aws lambda wrapper and also introduce ioredis adapter as I know lambdas can run in different machines based on the load and try it out.
What do you think? Is it worth or even makes sense to run socket.io in lambda ?

You can never open a direct socket connection to a Lambda function. You always have to go through an API, (either the AWS Lambda public API, or AWS API Gateway, or a Lambda function URL) to trigger AWS to invoke a Lambda function for you. The Lambda function does not get direct access to the network connection that initiated the request. So no, you can't use a technology like socket.io in Lambda. You would have to use API Gateway's websocket support to implement something similar https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/websocket-api-chat-app.html

What about the AWS ALB ? I am using that to orchestrate my other apis via rules, example /api/* goes to a particular lambda, and I wanted /socket.io/* to go to the typescript socketio lambda. I think I  understood that the ALB is dispatching a json payload and not a direct network request to the lambda that's why can't have real websocket connection

That's correct, the ALB is dispatching a JSON payload to the Lambda function, just like the other methods of invoking a Lambda function. There is no direct network connection  to the Lambda function.
